# Table data loads, briefly and unformatted, before jquery DataTables loads.

Tags: jquery, css, datatable

Table data loads, briefly and unformatted, before jquery DataTables loads. I have researched and found many say the solution is to hide the table with css and then show it in jquery with initComplete. I have tried the following but nothing seems to work:

```
css:
#tblAccount {
    visibility:hidden;
}
#tblCustomer {
    visibility: hidden;
}

jquery:
$(function () {
    $("[id*=tblAccount], [id *= tblCustomer]").prepend($("<thead></thead>").append($(this).find("tr:first"))).DataTable({
        "paging": true,
        "lengthChange": true,
        "searching": true,
        "ordering": true,
        "info": true,
        "autoWidth": true,
        "responsive": true,
        "dom": 'lBfrtip',
        "buttons": ['excel', 'print', 'pdfHtml5'],
        "initComplete": function () {
            $('#tblAccount').show().css({ visibility: "visible" });
        $('#tblCustomer').show().css({ visibility: "visible" });
        }

    });
})
```

Comment: jQuery's show() function changes the elements display property to 'block' or equivalent. So you'd have more luck removing the .css() part from both, and changing the initial css to 'display: none' instead of using visibility. What happens when you run your code above?

Comment: I tried changing the css as you suggested to 'display: none' and removed the css part from jquery. I get the same result with both, nothing changes. I still see the unformatted table for a brief second before DataTables loads. Cleared cache, same result.

Comment: where are you setting the css to display: none, is that in the css?

Comment: Yes, I'm displaying that in a style sheet like this:
#tblAccount { display: none; }

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you need both the .show() function and to change the css with css({ visibility: "visible" }).

If you start loading the page having "display : none" on #tblAccount and #tblCustomer then keep have

```
$('#tblAccount').show();
$('#tblCustomer').show();
```

in the initComplete function, you should get the functionality you are looking for.

Comment: Hi Sara, excuse the off topic comment (figured you can delete it after reading): I was inspired by your recent blog post to write about my own "bad days" (which took place in April and I had already vowed to forget about), and share my thoughts on how to build the community: [*What two very bad days (and everything else) on Stack Exchange taught me about building Stack Exchange's community*](https://thinkingtorus.weebly.com/blog/what-two-very-bad-days-and-everything-else-on-stack-exchange-taught-me-about-building-stack-exchanges-community).

Comment: Unfortunately I guess my reply to your post got stuck in the spam filter or somewhere, so I chose, against my better judgement, to start a [meta discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/331289/why-stack-exchange-is-no-longer-a-fun-place-for-learning-and-sharing-knowledge). My proposals, like your post, are received enthusiastically by the community (except with downvotes). Anyway, just thought you might like to take a look (preferably, the original 7000 word post on weebly). Nice post of yours by the way, and thanks for sharing!